# How can I efficiently record 3d games/3d programs in real-time?

Tags: nvidia, realtime, video-recording, obs-studio

As per subject would like to efficiently record 3d games/3d apps running full screen.

I have an Nvidia 2080 Ti and I've heard about NVENC and obs-studio.

Has anyone any suggestion?
Can I just use it out of the Ubuntu PPAs?

Thanks!